# Sandboxing, login items and launch App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox

Trying to make my app works with sandboxing I get stuck in this problem:

I need to add my App to login items so I've followed these steps:

- Creating an **HelperApp.app** (with `is agent = YES`) that at the open exec this code :

  ```
  NSString *appPath = @"/Applications/MyNewApp.app";
  [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appPath];
  [NSApp terminate:nil];
  ```

  This app is sandboxed.
- I added a copy build phase to my MyNewApp.app bundle with subpath `Contents/Library/LoginItems` and destination `wrapper`

  And obviously also the **MyNewApp.app** is sandboxed
- In **MyNewApp.app** I registered with `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` the bundle id for the **HelperApp.app**

Now all works correctly but... when **MyNewApp.app** tries to launch **MyNewApp.app** I get an error:

```
LSOpenFromURLSpec() returned -10827 for application /Applications/MyNewApp.app path (null).
```

But if I try to use the HelperApp.app to launch a not sandboxed (i.e. Steam.app) app it works like a charm!

Is there another way to launch the app? probably NSWorkSpace works with functions not allowed in sandbox context. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at my tutorial on [how to get launch at login working in the sandbox](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/).

Comment: good tutorial! But I can't understand why it works if I create a workspace with the 2 projects and it doesn't work if I use 2 different projects and I copy the helper app through the copy bundles.

Comment: Good question. I've to admit that I don't have an answer at hand, I found the working solution by trial & error..

Comment: Please add the basics to your answer. A link-only answer, which is what this is, becomes useless when you tutorial goes offline.

Comment: @dandan78 Such aa today :C